# How to have user choose cell in another worksheet, and then paste to it, with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wanting to select a range of cells from one worksheet, push a button, have the user select cells on another sheet in a different workbook, and have the copied cells paste there.

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub btnCopyPaste_Click()

Dim CopyWS As Worksheet
Set CopyWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CopySheet")

Dim rngMyRange As Range

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        Set rngMyRange = Selection

            Dim sCell As String
            sCell = Range(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick the Cell", Type:=8)).Value

        rngMyRange.Copy .Range(sCell) 'this is the bad line

    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

I'm trying to user an Application.InputBox to get the "cell to paste in" from the user, but I'm having trouble getting the relevant information about the cell back. Like, the workbook/worksheet location.

When I run the code and select the "cell to paste in" when prompted, the input box on the form shows this:  '[WorkbookName]SheetName'!$A$1 ..

Is this information stored in the background, so that I can access it with a command, or will I have to take this string and dissect it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: See the [`Application.InputBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) docs, specifically the paragraph that begins "If Type is 8, InputBox returns a Range object...", and the example immediately following. In fewer words - you should work with a `Range` object, not a `String`.

Comment: Note that the `.Value` member call will fail if the user cancels that prompt.

Comment: Thank you, I've corrected my code to the Method information: 
            Dim sCell As Range
            Set sCell = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Pick the cell", Type:=8)
However, I'm still getting errors when I'm trying to find the workbook and worksheet name.  I've tried more than a few variations ... Range(sCell).Worksheet.Name, sCell.Worksheet.Name, sCell.Address, etc., etc. 
I get the "invalid procedure call or argument" error. How do you access that information?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
Private Sub btnCopyPaste_Click()

    Dim rngMyRange As Range, c As Range

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        Set rngMyRange = Selection

        On Error Resume Next 'in case user cancels
        Set c = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick the Cell", Type:=8)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not c Is Nothing Then rngMyRange.Copy c

    End If

End Sub
```